# What is the difference between React node and React component and virtual dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between these three concepts :

- **React node**
- **React component**
- **virtual dom** ?

Is there any ? How are these three concepts related ?

After I have read [this](https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-semantics.html), the difference is still not clear.

[This](https://cmapscloud.ihmc.us/viewer/cmap/1QQKSFCL5-DF2BH2-2SS0) concept map below summarises my current understanding, and right now it seems to me that these three concepts are all the same. Are they ? Are they not ? If not, what's the difference?

[image]